# Generic config file parser setter in C++

Tags: c++, enums, configuration-files, unions

I'm working on a generic config file parser.

*First*, it is supposed to call a function to set the data types of the variables.

```
enum type {a,b,c}; 
union{int a; double b; float c;};
void SetTypes(type x, string *names){ 
// names[] contains the names of the variables
// type is what data type from the union needs to be used
union name.x;   //------(1)
}
```

But I'm facing issues with the string[] length.

So, I'm making my function in the following manner

```
void setTypes(type a, string name...){}
```

Is there any way of making it more efficient; so that I could bundle the same type of data together?

*The aim of this program is so that we don't have to predefine the data types in our code, making config parsers more flexible.*

The *second* issue here is in line marked (1)
How do I make `<union> <varname>.<enum>` 
happen? where varname and enum are variables

**Edit 1 : Added example**

For example,

```
struct EXAMPLE{
/*Some Code*/
 enum allowed_types {vec3D, complex_num};
union {
Vector3D vec3D;
Complex complex_num;
};
/* More Code*/
};
```

when I call the function in the manner

```
setType(vec3D, {"point1", "point 2", "point3"}, complex_num, {"num1", "num2"});
```

Then I need the function to make the variables (each of the struct) 
`point1 of type Vector3D
point2 of type Vector3D
point3 of type Vector3D
num1 of type Complex
num2 of type Complex`

I'm using enum so that I have more control over what types I use.
I'm using union so that I could store the values in a hashmap using a pointer, to minimize space loss.

Comment: Recommend an edit: `a` is used three different ways making for a confusing read.

Comment: I'm a little confused here. What issues are you having with the length of names? Are they millions? And are you really sure you need an union to store the data? Can you be more precise on the desired behaviour and provide an example?

Comment: @user4581301 it is the same `a` being used.

Comment: @user1620443 Added an example

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, the program should, *at runtime* decide which kind of data its binary representation, well, represent. This means that you have no idea of what kind of data to use *at compile time*. One option is to have different collections of different types of data; or you may want classes which inherit from a `GenericData`, and use virtual calls to deal with different kind of data. About memory efficiency, if you save a complex number in a union with a 3d vector, you are wasting 33% of the memory, aren't you?

Comment: Example of the point I am trying to make: http://ideone.com/Dhg0nf

Answer (score 0):

You may use a `unordered_map<string, int> data_type;` to store the type of each "name".
Then when you want to return the value, you can switch the data type and use appropriately.

```
switch(data_type[s]){
   case vec3d:
       coordinates.push_back(data[s].vec3d);
       break;
   case complex_num:
       r = get_real(data[s].complex);
       break;
}
```